# Regex modify capturing group

Tags: regex

I have this Regex

```
^(?!.*\b(?:https?:\/\/|www\.))\w+(?:\.\w+)*\.\w{2,}(?:,\w+(?:\.\w+)*\.\w{2,})+$
```

that captures multiple URL separated by commas
caputres `google.com,facebook.com` but not with extra characters like `google.com/home.php?,facebook.com/pages/#ref=?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your URLs won't contain a comma, you can add another **optional non-capturing group** in your regex like this:

```
^(?!.*\b(?:https?:\/\/|www\.))\w+(?:\.\w+)*\.\w{2,}(?:\/[^,]*)?(?:,\w+(?:\.\w+)*\.\w{2,}(?:\/[^,]*)?)*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bQZZgA/2)

Note addition of an *optional* non-capturing group in regex:

- `(?:\/[^,]*)?`: That matches text starting with `/` followed by 0 or more of any character except a comma. `?` makes this group **optional**

Comment: but is it possible to make it accpept multiple links not just two? like it should match `google.com/home.php?,facebook.com/pages/#ref=?,facebook.com,google.com`